# Using segues to automatically rotate views

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard

I have a UIViewController in landscape which modally displays a UINavigationController in portrait. When I use a modal segue connection to get from the view controller to the navigation controller, for some reason initially the view controller is forced to the portrait orientation (when initially it should be in the landscape orientation). When I remove the segue, things work as expected.

The desired behaviour is to use a modal segue from an interface in the landscape orientation to another interface in the portrait orientation.

Any idea what's going on here? Or how to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Use notifications.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated{
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:@selector(receivedRotate:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];
}

-(void) receivedRotate: (NSNotification*) notification
{
UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"/* Segue from the VCPotrait to VCLandscape*/" sender: self];
}
}
```

The segue should be modal.

Comment: Ehm, I think you misunderstood my question. I want to know how to -force- the iPhone to change orientation when it opens up the modal view controller. I already know how to deal with orientations that are caused by the user.

Comment: I guess there is a device orientation property. This should enable you to set the orientation.

Comment: If you're referring to UIDevice's orientation property, that's read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that initially the ***navigation*** controller is forced to the portrait orientation?

I've done this with UIViewController subclasses, where I have a view controller in portrait orientation that does a modal segue to a view controller in landscape orientation. The key was telling the second controller not to autorotate to any orientations I didn't want:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

You'll want to subclass UINavigationController to be able to set that, I think.

The segue is defined as Modal in the storyboard, and the code in the first (presenter) view controller looks pretty normal:

```
-(IBAction) zoomIn:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ZoomIn" sender: self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ZoomIn"]) {
        OSZoomViewController *zoom = [segue destinationViewController];
        zoom.image = ...;
        zoom.presenter = self;
    } 
}
```